# Is there a code for deadlock detection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, deadlock

I want to find a code that implements the deadlock detection algorithm in any programming language.

Algorithms (System steps):

1. Mark each process that has a row in the Allocation matrix of all zeros.
2. Initialize a temporary vector W to equal the Available vector.
3. Find an index i such that process i is currently unmarked and the i the row of Q is less than or equal to W . That is, Qik ≤ Wk, for 1 ≤ k ≤ m . If no such row is found, terminate the algorithm.
4. If such a row is found, mark process i and add the corresponding row of the allocation matrix to W . That is, set Wk = Wk + Aik, for 1 ≤ k ≤ m . Return to step 3.

User input:
1- Claim matrix
2- allocated matrix
3- available matrix

System output:
1- print C-A matrix
2- print W vector , allocated and C-A  matrices  for each step
3- finally print the marked processes(that are not deadlocked)  and unmarked processes(that are deadlocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to look for the code. I found parts of it online in Java and did some edits. Hope it may help ..

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
    
    class Main {
        static int safe[] = new int[20]; //Array for safe
        static int unsafe[] = new int[20]; // Array for unsafe
    
        static boolean safe(int available[], int allocated[][], int need[][], int n1, int m1) {
            int n = n1; //number of processes
            int m = m1; //number of resources
            int nd[][] = new int[n][m];
            int work[] = new int[m];
            int alloc[][] = new int[n][m];
    
    
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { //Work var
                work[i] = available[i];
            }
    
            /** Print Available Matrix */
            System.out.println("*** Available Matrix /n");
            for( int i = 0; i < work.length; i++ ) {
                System.out.println( work[i] + " " );
            }
    
    
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    alloc[i][j] = allocated[i][j];
                }
            }
    
            /** Print Allocated Matrix */
            System.out.println("*** Allocated Matrix /n");
            for( int i = 0; i < alloc.length; i++ ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < alloc[i].length; j++ ) {
                    System.out.print( alloc[i][j] + " " );
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    
    
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    nd[i][j] = need[i][j];
                }
            }
    
            /** Print Need Matrix */
            System.out.println("*** Need Matrix ");
            for( int i = 0; i < nd.length; i++ ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < nd[i].length; j++ ) {
                    System.out.print( nd[i][j] + " " );
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    
            /* Hold the finished processes */
            boolean finish[] = new boolean[n];
    
    
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                finish[i] = false;
            }
    
    
            int check = 0;
            int check1 = 0;
    
    
            do {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    boolean flag = true; /* Temp Flag */
                    if ( finish[i] == false ) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                            if (work[j] < nd[i][j]) {
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
    
                        /* If available resources are greater than needed, then assign allocated resources
                         for processing */
                        if ( flag ) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                                work[j] += alloc[i][j];
                            }
                            safe[check] = i; /* Put the process number (Pi) in the safe Matrix */
                            check++;
                            finish[i] = true;
                        } else {
                            unsafe[check] = i; /* Put the process number (Pi) in the safe Matrix */
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                check1++; /* Start on the next process */
            } while ( check < n && check1 < n);
    
            if (check > n) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        /** Main Function */
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(isr);
    
            int n, m;
            System.out.println("Enter no. of processes: "); /* Enter number of processes. */
            n = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter no. of resources: "); /* Enter number of Resources. */
            m = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
    
            int availableArr[] = new int[m]; // Matrix of available instances
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter no. of available instances resources: " + i);
    
                availableArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
            }
    
            System.out.println("Enter allocation of resources: ");
            // Allocation Matrix. //
            int allocArr[][] = new int[n][m];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    /* Enter allocation of instances of resources. */
                    System.out.println("Enter allocation instances of resources: " + j + " for process p" + i);
                    /* Enter allocation of instances of resources. */
                    allocArr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                }
            }
    
            System.out.println("enter maximum of resources: ");
            int maxArr[][] = new int[n][m];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    System.out.println("enter max instances of resources:" + j + "for process p" + i);
    
                    maxArr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                }
            }
    
            /** Print Max Matrix */
            System.out.println("*** Max Matrix \n");
            for( int i = 0; i < maxArr.length; i++ ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < maxArr[i].length; j++ ) {
                    System.out.print( maxArr[i][j] + " " );
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    
            /* Calculate Need Matrix */
            int needArr[][] = new int[n][m];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    /* Need= Max - Allocation */
                    needArr[i][j] = maxArr[i][j] - allocArr[i][j];
                }
            }
    
            if ( safe( availableArr, allocArr, needArr, n, m )) {
                System.out.println("System is at a safe state");
                System.out.print("System's Safe sequence:");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.print( "P" + safe[i] + " " );
                }
                System.out.println();}
                else{
                    System.out.println("The system is at unsafe state");
                System.out.println("System's UnSafe sequence");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.print( "P" + unsafe[i] + " " );
                }
            }
            System.out.println("System's UnSafe sequence"); //to print the unsafe sequence if the it's a safe state (lead to deadlock)
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print( "P" + unsafe[i] + " " );
            }
    
    
        }}
```